# How to prompt for user password when running my code?

Tags: go, input, terminal, passwords

Hope everyone is having a good week. I’m trying to get my code to prompt a user to enter their password. as of right now if you run the code and do --help you get a few flag parameters. So I don’t want the user to show their password via the terminal prompt. Basically give the pram and fire the code and enter password. I hope I explained it right, on what I’m trying to do. I’m still green in Go. example:

```
-ipAddress string ip address of the managed server to be added
-password string hmc user password
-url string hmc REST api url
-user string hmc user



package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/tls"
    "encoding/xml"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/cookiejar"
    "text/template"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
)
//
// XML parsing structures
//
type Feed struct {
    Entry struct {
        Content struct {
            ManagementConsole struct {
                Metadata struct {
                    Atom struct {
                        AtomID      string `xml:"AtomID"`
                        AtomCreated string `xml:"AtomCreated"`
                    } `xml:"Atom"`
                } `xml:"Metadata"`
            } `xml:"ManagementConsole"`
        } `xml:"content"`
    } `xml:"entry"`
}

// HTTP session struct
//
type Session struct {
    client   *http.Client
    User     string
    Password string
    url      string
}
type Manage struct {
    Ipaddress string
}
func NewSession(user string, password string, url string) *Session {
    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }
    jar, err := cookiejar.New(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return &Session{client: &http.Client{Transport: tr, Jar: jar}, User: user, Password: password, url: url}
}
func (s *Session) doLogon() {
    authurl := s.url + "/rest/api/web/Logon"
    // template for login request
    logintemplate := `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <LogonRequest xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/systems/power/firmware/web/mc/2012_10/" schemaVersion="V1_1_0">
    <Metadata>
      <Atom/>
    </Metadata>
    <UserID kb="CUR" kxe="false">{{.User}}</UserID>
    <Password kb="CUR" kxe="false">{{.Password}}</Password>
  </LogonRequest>`
    tmpl := template.New("logintemplate")
    tmpl.Parse(logintemplate)
    authrequest := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := tmpl.Execute(authrequest, s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    request, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", authurl, authrequest)
    // set request headers

    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ibm.powervm.web+xml; type=LogonRequest")
    request.Header.Set("Accept", "application/vnd.ibm.powervm.web+xml; type=LogonResponse")
    request.Header.Set("X-Audit-Memento", "hmctest")
    response, err := s.client.Do(request)
    fmt.Println("\n")
    fmt.Println(response)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        defer response.Body.Close()
        if response.StatusCode != 200 {
            log.Fatalf("Error status code: %d", response.StatusCode)
        }
    }
}
func (s *Session) getManaged()(string) {
    hmcUUID :=""
    // mgdurl := s.url + "/rest/api/uom/LogicalPartition"
    mgdurl := s.url + "/rest/api/uom/ManagementConsole"
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", mgdurl, nil)
    request.Header.Set("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
    response, err := s.client.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        defer response.Body.Close()
        contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        if response.StatusCode != 200 {
            log.Fatalf("Error getting LPAR informations. status code: %d", response.StatusCode)
        }
        var feed Feed
        new_err := xml.Unmarshal(contents, &feed)
        if new_err != nil {
            log.Fatal(new_err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("AtomID: %v\n", feed.Entry.Content.ManagementConsole.Metadata.Atom.AtomID)
        fmt.Printf("AtomCreated: %v\n", feed.Entry.Content.ManagementConsole.Metadata.Atom.AtomCreated)
        hmcUUID = feed.Entry.Content.ManagementConsole.Metadata.Atom.AtomID

    }

    return hmcUUID
}
func (s *Session) addManaged(uuid *string, i *Manage){
    addManagedURl := s.url + "/rest/api/uom/ManagementConsole/" + *uuid + "/do/AddManagedSystem"
    addManagedTemplate := `<JobRequest:JobRequest
 xmlns:JobRequest="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/systems/power/firmware/web/mc/2012_10/"
 xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/systems/power/firmware/web/mc/2012_10/"
 xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace/k2" schemaVersion="V1_0">
       <Metadata>
           <Atom/>
       </Metadata>
       <RequestedOperation kb="CUR" kxe="false" schemaVersion="V1_0">
           <Metadata>
               <Atom/>
           </Metadata>
           <OperationName kb="ROR" kxe="false">AddManagedSystem</OperationName>
           <GroupName kb="ROR" kxe="false">ManagementConsole</GroupName>
       </RequestedOperation>
       <JobParameters kb="CUR" kxe="false" schemaVersion="V1_0">
           <Metadata>
               <Atom/>
           </Metadata>
         <JobParameter schemaVersion="V1_0"><Metadata><Atom/></Metadata>
            <ParameterName kb="ROR" kxe="false">host</ParameterName>
            <ParameterValue kb="CUR" kxe="false">{{.Ipaddress}}</ParameterValue>
         </JobParameter>
        <JobParameter schemaVersion="V1_0"><Metadata><Atom/></Metadata>
            <ParameterName kb="ROR" kxe="false">password</ParameterName>
            <ParameterValue kb="CUR" kxe="false">abcc123</ParameterValue>
         </JobParameter>
       </JobParameters>
   </JobRequest:JobRequest>  `
    tmpl := template.New("addManagedTemplate")
    tmpl.Parse(addManagedTemplate)
    addrequest := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err := tmpl.Execute(addrequest, i)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    request, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", addManagedURl, addrequest)
    // set request headers
    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ibm.powervm.web+xml; type=JobRequest")
    request.Header.Set("Accept", "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8")
    // request.Header.Set("Expect", "")
    response, err := s.client.Do(request)
    fmt.Println("\n")
    fmt.Println(response)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        defer response.Body.Close()
        if response.StatusCode != 200 {
            log.Fatalf("Error status code: %d", response.StatusCode)
        }
    }
}
func readPassword(prompt string) string {
    fmt.Print(prompt)
    pass, err := terminal.ReadPassword(int(os.Stdin.Fd()))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    println()
    return string(pass)
}

func main() {
    // Variables
    password := readPassword("hmc Password: ")
    //confirm := readPassword("Confirm hmc Password: ")
    user := flag.String("user", "", "hmc user")
    password := flag.String("password", "", "hmc user password")
    url := flag.String("url", "", "hmc REST api url")
    ipAddress := flag.String("ipAddress", "", "ip address of the managed server to be added")
    flag.Parse()
    //initialize new http session
    fmt.Printf("server %s is being added.../n", *ipAddress)
    session := NewSession(*user, *password, *url)
    //var password string = readPassword("hmc password")
    session.doLogon()
    hmcUUID := session.getManaged()
    ipaddr := &Manage {
        Ipaddress: *ipAddress,
    }
    session.addManaged(&hmcUUID, ipaddr)
    fmt.Println(hmcUUID)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal.

You can do something like this:

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "syscall"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
)
func ReadPass() (password *bytes.Buffer, err error) {
var fi, _ = os.Stdin.Stat()

var pass []byte

isChardev := fi.Mode()&os.ModeCharDevice != 0
isNamedPipe := fi.Mode()&os.ModeNamedPipe != 0
if ! isChardev || isNamedPipe {
    sin := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    pass, _, err = sin.ReadLine()
} else {
    _, _ = os.Stderr.WriteString(fmt.Sprint("passphrase: "))
    pass, err = terminal.ReadPassword(syscall.Stdin)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer fmt.Println()
}
return bytes.NewBuffer(pass), err
}
```

The above example is taken from here:
https://github.com/tox2ik/go-smux/blob/master/io/terminal.go

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. With this code wouldn’t you have to capture the the password? Or something like that? Not sure